# Load CSVs - unable to pass file paths from dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, databricks, azure-databricks

Below code works fine:

```
val Path = Seq (
"dbfs:/mnt/testdata/2019/02/Calls2019-02-03.tsv",
"dbfs:/mnt/testdata/2019/02/Calls2019-02-02.tsv"
)

val Calls = spark.read
       .format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
       .option("header", "true")
       .option("delimiter", "\t")
       .schema(schema)
       .load(Path: _*)
```

But I want to get the paths from the dataframe and the below code is not working.

```
val tsvPath = 
Seq(
 FinalFileList
.select($"Path")
.filter($"FileDate">MaxStartTime)
.collect.mkString(",")
.replaceAll("[\\[\\]]","")
 )

val Calls = spark.read
       .format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
       .option("header", "true")
       .option("delimiter", "\t")
       .schema(schema)
       .load(tsvPath: _*)
```

Error:

```
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Path does not exist: dbfs:/mnt/testdata/2019/02/Calls2019-02-03.tsv,dbfs:/mnt/testdata/2019/02/Calls2019-02-02.tsv;
```

Looks like it is taking the path as `"/mnt/file1.tsv, /mnt/file2.tsv"` instead of `"/mnt/file1.tsv","/mnt/file2.tsv"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Looks like it is taking the path as "/mnt/file1.tsv, /mnt/file2.tsv" instead of "/mnt/file1.tsv","/mnt/file2.tsv"

I suspect your problem is here:

```scala
.collect.mkString(",")
.replaceAll("[\\[\\]]","")
```

`.mkString` combines the strings together into one. One possible solution here is to split again after replacing:

```scala
.collect.mkString(",")
.replaceAll("[\\[\\]]","")
.split(",")
```

Another would be to just replace each element instead of combining into a string:

```scala
.collect.foreach(_.replaceAll("[\\[\\]]",""))
```

Whichever one is more suited to you.

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick! 
What we needed is Array[String] and not the String.